# Django Rest Framework - PUT to (many=True) PrimaryKeyRelatedField()

Tags: django, jquery, django-rest-framework

http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations.html#primarykeyrelatedfield

I am trying to write to a `PrimaryKeyRelatedField()` and, although a 200 status is returned, an empty value is being input for the field in question, rather than multiple values.

```
$.ajax({url:'<MY MODELVIEWSET>/<ID>', type:'PUT', data:{'field1':'xyz', <FIELD IN QUESTION WITH PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True)>:[1,2,3]}})
```

**--> Updated field is empty**

Updates are successful and correct when only one value is given for this field.

```
$.ajax({url:'<MY MODELVIEWSET>/<ID>', type:'PUT', data:{'field1':'xyz', <FIELD IN QUESTION WITH PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True)>:1}})
```

**--> Updates correctly**

Comment: Can you show your model and serializer definition?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set traditional to true so jquery will encode the params that contains arrays in a way that django will understand:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'<MY MODELVIEWSET>/<ID>', 
    type:'PUT',
    traditional: true, 
    data:{field1:'xyz', field2:[1,2,3]}
})
```

See [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) for the difference between default and traditional encoding.